# Как динамически задать один из стандартных жестов?

Tags: c++, radstudio, firemonkey, gestures

```
ListBox1->Touch->GestureManager = GestureManager1;
ListBox1->Touch->StandardGestures = TStandardGesture::sgLeft;
```

Попробовал так, выдает ошибку:

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Answer (score 0):

В тексте ошибки видно, что компилятор не может преобразовать тип `TStandardGesture` в `TStandardGestures` (имена отличаются только одной буквой `s` на конце). Также в ошибке сказано, что второй тип по-сути является псевдонимом для шаблонного класса [`Set`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__Set.html). Этот класс представляет собой набор (множество) значений и для помещения значения в это множество предусмотрена перегрузка `operator<<`:

```
ListBox1->Touch->StandardGestures << TStandardGesture::sgLeft;
```